# Is there a Simpler way to Show ListView Item activities when you have lots of items?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, android-listview, onclick

I have a listView which get information from the XML(listview of drinks and title, description) I have made onClick but i wanted to know if there is a simpler way of showing the activities for each item on mylistView. I have more than 10 items on my listView does that mean I have to Create more than 10 new Activities_xml each with same layout Just displaying more Information about the Clicked item. I'm going to have other parts of the Android App to have more ListViews(maybe 10 listView which will equal 100 Activities in my Layout Folder). possibly having minimum of 10 activities per listView.

Would be helpful if you let me know if this is right way to do it or if there's a simlper way. thank you

Comment: no, you don't need so many activites, seperate data from UI elements ... you need only 2 activities/fragments one for list and second for details ... and some database(sqlite or simple json/xml file - to store drink's descriptions)

Comment: Try use fragments rather than activities. You do not need to declare fragments in your manifest and you need to for activities

Comment: hum.... looks like you should study a little bit more the way Android is working. Read the http://developer.android.com/training/index.html, and try some examples to get use of how it's work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is an example code on how you should, details will change to exactly what u need, and what names you put to stuff, but that's the base idea of it.

make sure to check the `Bundle` docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

to launch the "drink details"

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class)
i.putExtra("drinkName", "coca");
i.putExtra("drinkSize", "500ml");
startActivity(i);
```

then on the details activity

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
super.onCreate(savedInstnace);

String drinkName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("drinkName");
String drinkSize = getIntent().getExtras().getString("drinkSize");


// then you can assign those `String` values to your `TextView` on the layout

}
```

Comment: i've tried this it works ok, but How about if i want to get the strings from the strings xml which will have all the drinks names and descriptions and sizes. and most importantly to Display an Image of the Cola with DrinkName and DrinkSize,Do I need to set set the Image to the ImageView with putExtra too?

Comment: So many ways of doing it, listing 3 ways from most simple to most complex... 1) You can pass an integer with the XML resource ID of the item. 2) You can put your XML items as an array (an array of items inside your xml) and pass and integer with the position on that array. 3) You can pass the name of the XML resource and find the ID of it using 'resources.getIdentifier()'.